Does anyone know how to not have a date change daily so that a date created date can stay accurate online excel
I'm running into the issue on online excel where my formula is printing 1/0/1900 as the date. I want my formula to print a date, created date. So essentially, the formula will respond to someone adding the status of the task as either open or complete, then the following column would print the current date and not change as more tasks are added on later dates.
=IF(H4 <> "", IF(I4 = "", NOW(),I4),"") 
I tried changing it to today() instead of now() but same results. Not sure if anyone else has experienced this issue with excel online. The formula works fine on normal desktop excel, but for some reason not on online. I've also verified my time zone and that my calculation option is set to automatic.

today() and now() are volatile functions which means they update any time the sheet recalculates such as when you save. I enter the time and date as fixed values with "cmd+;" and "ctrl+;", so you could consider that or some vba.

If possible instruct the user to hit CTRL + ; to input the current date as a static value in whatever cell they have selected (aiming to put it into the correct one). Otherwise you'll have to put together some considerable vba to do this for you but leave it alone once it's done, which can get messy fast.

This is a circular reference and I do not believe online allows those at all, while the desktop can be set to allow them.  Excel Online also does not have events so coding would not be automatic.  Basically the only choice you have is what is above and training.

So is it safe to say that some thing like stamping when a row gets data inputted cant be created on online excel ?

For what purpose? You can see which user did which changes when necessary. Do you need it for calculation purposes?

So i want for when users input a new row (in my case a row that contains tasks information) it populates the date created so that everyone can keep track of when a ticket or issue was opened/created. The formula works on excel desktop but it doesnt work on excel online.
